# problems is mini-filter while filtering volume mounts

Tags: driver, minifilter

[OS: WinXP on VirtualBox, HostOS: win7]

We are developing a mini-filter driver and we are trying to block mounting of usb devices based on some conditions.

the mini-filter watches for `IRP_MJ_VOLUME_MOUNT` and whenever a usb drive is inserted, in the `pre-callback`, it asks userland whether or not to allow mount the drive using FltSendMessage.
In the userland, after `FltGetMessage` and before `FltReplyMessage`, certain conditions are checked and corresponding value is replied back to the driver.

This all is working fine, but we are experiencing two problems or lets say inconveniences.

1. The condition checking takes about 4-5 seconds [data is sent and received over network]. During this period, the Windows Explorer just hangs. And whatever the actions such as navigations, are performed as soon as `FltReplyMessage` is called. If I click anywhere such as the start menu, nothing happens until `FltReplyMessage` is called. Other applications such as VLC function normally [ie, the disk can be accessed].
2. When the usb drive is not allowed to mount the volume, it continues to try mounting the volume several times!
   The workaround we used is to maintain a list of recently inserted devices and reject them if the GUID is present in the list.
   I read somewhere that the mount point can be deleted using `DeleteVolumeMountPoint` and if we need to allow that device in future then we need to delete a reg key which contains the unique ID of device which can be obtained sending `MOUNTDEV_UNIQUE_ID` to the device. We tried to achieve this, but were unsuccessful to correctly obtain the unique ID. [we were unable to allocate enough memory for the `MOUNTDEV_UNIQUE_ID` structure. Tried `new` and `malloc(enough size)` but then `sizeof(varUniqueID)` returned just 4, and calling `DeviceIoControl` with that resulted in "More Data is available" error. We are doing in userland. Should this be done in kernel?]

Whew! a long post!
We would really appreciate any help we can get!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

1. As far as your first concern there is not much you can do unless there is a way you can cache the data needed in the driver based on volume unique ids.
   This way there will only be a **Flt** call per mount.
   I am not sure about your requirements, but if the data needed to make a decision is over network then you will suffer from this delay one way or another. It is crucial for the driver to be able to cache its own data without having to even call into user-mode after a first mount attempt of the same device.
2. For the second point for sure you could do it in either user-mode or kernel-mode. Could you provide a code snip to check for any mistakes ?

Cheers,
Gabriel